# how to apply storyboard animation to multiple xaml element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have created a storyboard animation, and it works for my one XAML element, however how can i apply it to multiple XAML elements ones?

here is the XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="FlipOpen">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-90"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-270"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-360"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

and the controlled XAML:

```
                        <StackPanel Background="Blue" Width="420" x:Name="Front">
                            <StackPanel.Projection>
                                <PlaneProjection/>
                            </StackPanel.Projection>
                            <TextBlock Text="Front" FontSize="25" Height="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="alcim" FontSize="10" Height=" 20"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="Back" Width="420" Background="Red">
                            <StackPanel.Projection>
                                <PlaneProjection RotationY="-270" />
                            </StackPanel.Projection>
                            <TextBlock Text="Hátlap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
```

How can i create the controlled party in code (multiple times), and then apply the storyboard to it? because they can't have the same x:Name property...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking... Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738976/is-it-possible-to-start-same-animation-for-different-controls-at-same-start-time/24739137#24739137

Comment: hmm kind of... i thought there is an easier way to link one storyboard to multiple items..

Comment: Like I said, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. My linked question/answer *might* be related, it might not. Could you clarify the question at all?

Comment: i want to use the defined storyboard on multiple items (for example 5-6 grids that contain those stackpanels) and then when all the grid should have that storyboard effect. if you click on the grid, the storyboard would play on the elements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Define your storyboard as a resource and reference it from the controls you want animate or from a style.

```
  <Storyboard x:Key="FlipOpenStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-90"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
```

Define in the stack panel when you want start the animation.

```
    <StackPanel Background="Blue" Width="420" x:Name="Front">
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpenStoryboard}" />
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <StackPanel.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection/>
        </StackPanel.Projection>

        <TextBlock Text="Front" FontSize="25" Height="40"/>
        <TextBlock Text="alcim" FontSize="10" Height=" 20"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I don't have the PlaneProjection control so below I provide you a working example of animating the Height of the panel.

The animation:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FlipOpenStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" >
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="500"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

The panel:

```
<StackPanel Background="Blue" Width="420" Height="100">
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpenStoryboard}" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>

    <TextBlock Text="Front" FontSize="25" Height="40"/>
    <TextBlock Text="alcim" FontSize="10" Height=" 20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This sounds good, i tried it, but i keep getting XamlParseException when i start the project

Comment: That means there's a formatting error in your xaml. Make sure all the tags are properly closed. I edited my answer and included a working example.

Comment: hmm it still drops the same error for me, even when i have put it on a new project too

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong not seeing the code. Try with a simpler example i.e. animating the Height as in the example I included and then build up to what you want to achieve step by step.